# jq 1.5 - Change existing element or add new if does not exist

Tags: json, traversal, jq

## Using:

- jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe (Ubuntu 17.10)
- Compose the queries: https://jqplay.org/

## Goals and conditions:

1. Replace an child object value with another value, at any depth, having parents objects or arrays, for example:

   - if .spec.template.spec.containers[**n**].env[**n**]**.name** == "CHANGEME" then
   - .spec.template.spec.containers[**n**].env[**n**]**.value** = "xx"
   - where **n** >=0
2. If any of the parents of **.name** do not exist, should be able to add them on the fly instead of exiting with an error
3. The output JSON should have at least the same elements as the input JSON, no existing elements should be lost
4. No duplicates are allowed within the elements of an array, but the order **must be preserved**, so functions like `unique` cannot be used

## Sample input JSON:

The structure is actually imposed, so I have to obey it. An object "path" usually is something like: `.spec.template.spec.containers[0].spec.env[1].name`. You could also have .containers[1], and so on. This is highly variable, and sometimes some elements **could** exist or not, depends on a schema definition of that particular JSON.

```
[
  {
    "kind": "StatefulSet",
    "spec": {
      "serviceName": "cassandra",
      "template": {
        "spec": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "name": "cassandra",
              "env": [
                {
                  "name": "CASSANDRA_SEEDS",
                  "value": "cassandra-0.cassandra.kong.svc.cluster.local"
                },
                {
                  "name": "CHANGEME",
                  "value": "K8"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

## Scenarios

1. Replace an existing value while preserving the input structure, works as expected:

   - `jq -r 'map({name:"CHANGEME",value: "xx"} as $v | (.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | select(.name==$v.name))|=$v)'`
2. Let's assume I want to do the same, only that .env1 is the parent array of the object {name:"",value:""}. The expected output should be:

   ```
   [
     {
       "kind": "StatefulSet",
       "spec": {
         "serviceName": "cassandra",
         "template": {
           "spec": {
             "containers": [
               {
                 "name": "cassandra",
                 "env": [
                   {
                     "name": "CASSANDRA_SEEDS",
                     "value": "cassandra-0.cassandra.kong.svc.cluster.local"
                   },
                   {
                     "name": "CHANGEME",
                     "value": "K8"
                   }
                 ],
                 "env1": [
                   {
                     "name": "CHANGEME",
                     "value": "xx"
                   }
                 ]
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ]
   ```

   - For this, I have tried to add an object env1 on the fly:

     - `jq -r 'map({name:"CHANGEME",value: "xx"} as $v | (.spec.template.spec.containers[] | if .env1 ==  null then .+={env1:[$v]} | .env1  else .env1 end | .[] | select(.name==$v.name))|=$v)'`

       - works if **.env1** exists, else:
       - error: Invalid path expression near attempt to access element "env1" of {"name":"cassandra","env"..
       - same results if using notations like `.env//[$v]` or `.env//=.env[$v]`
     - `jq -r 'map({name:"CHANGEME",value: "xx"} as $v | (.spec.template.spec.containers[].env1 | .[if length<0 then 0 else length end]) |= $v)'`

       - works if .env1 does **not** exist
       - adds another element if the array .env1 exists, potentially duplicating objects
   - Eventually I have managed to create a working filter:

     - `jq -r 'def defarr: if length<=0 then .[0] else .[] end; def defarr(item): if length<=0 then .[0] else foreach .[] as $item ([]; if $item.name == item then $item else empty end; .) end; map({name:"CHANGEME",value: "xx"} as $v | (.spec.template.spec | .containers1 | defarr | .env1 | defarr($v.name) ) |=$v)'`

       - this works as expected, however is too long and heavy and have to add the custom functions after each potential array in the object hierarchy

## The question

Is there any way to simplify all this, make it a bit more generic to handle any number of parents, arrays or not?

Thank you.

Comment: Vanilla JS seems simpler than this ([tag:nodejs] by example)

Comment: I am using jq as part of bash scripts to generate deployments and change various configs for kubernetes cluster. I preffer jq since is lightweight and is already provided with major Linux releases.

Comment: The problem with your specification of "foo" is that .parent1.parent2[].parent3.parent4[].parent5[] is not really a path or path specification, because it contains occurrences of `[]`. Such expressions are useful because they can be used to retrieve multiple values, but it would probably help if you think of a path as an array consisting only of strings and integers.  Such arrays are in fact used by jq's `getpath` and `setpath`, and for good reason.

Comment: Understood, I will in fact remove that fantasy spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to reach a very good form:

1. Added the following functions in `~/.jq`:

   ```
   def arr:
       if length<=0 then .[0] else .[] end;

   def arr(f):
       if length<=0 then
           .[0]
       else
           .[]|select(f)
       end//.[length];

   def when(COND; ACTION):
       if COND? // null then ACTION else . end;

   # Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
   def walk(f):
     . as $in
     | if type == "object" then
         reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
           ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
     elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
     else f
     end;

   def updobj(f):
     walk(when(type=="object"; f));
   ```
2. A typical filter will look like this:

   ```
   jq -r '{name:"CHANGEME",value: "xx"} as $v |
       map( when(.kind == "StatefulSet";
                 .spec.template.spec.containers|arr|.env|arr(.name==$v.name)) |= $v)'
   ```

The result will be that all objects that do not exist already will be created. The convention here is to use the `arr` functions for each object that you want to be an array, and at the end use a boolean condition and an object to replace the matched one or add to the parent array, if not matched.

3. If you know the path is always there, and so are the object you want to update, `walk` is more elegant:

   ```
   jq -r 'map(updobj(select(.name=="CHANGEME").value|="xx"))'
   ```

---

Thank you @peak for your effort and inspiring the solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### "The question"

In answer to **The question**: Yes. jq 1.5 has `keys_unsorted`, so you can use the following def of `walk/1`, which is now standard in the “master” version of jq:

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;
```

For further details and examples, see the “development” version of the jq manual, the jq FAQ https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ, etc.

#### "No duplicates are allowed within the elements of an array"

This is readily accomplished using `index/1`; you might like to use a helper function such as:

```
def ensure_has($x): if index([$x]) then . else . + [$x] end;
```

#### "If any of the parents of .name do not exist, should be able to add them on the fly"

If I understand this requirement correctly, it will useful for you to know that jq will create objects based on assignments, e.g.

```
{} | .a.b.c = 1
```

yields

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":1}}}
```

Thus, using your example, you will probably want to include something like this in your `walk`:

```
if type == "object" and has("spec")
   then (.spec.template.spec.containers? // null) as $existing
   | if $existing then .spec.template.spec.containers |= ... 
     else .spec.template.spec.containers = ...
     end
else .
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
1. I am not sure how to use walk to achieve what I need. I have tried it a bit and I can't figure out it's usage, especially if some elements are in fact arrays that are expected in the input but do not really exist (yet).  

2. Indeed, jq can generate objects like that, but the structure varies a lot, some of those objects are arrays within objects within arrays, and so on, to infinity and beyond :)  

3. Taking your last suggestion: what if .template does not exist? or the second .spec, or .containers (that is in fact an array not an object type)?

Comment: Using `walk(if type=="object" then (select(.name=="CHANGEME")|.value)|="x" else . end)` will update the existing {name:"CHANGEME",value:"**something**"} to value:"x", but only if is there. So far, I have not specified the path, and this is an improvment. However, if any of the objects in the path are missing, this will return null or []

Comment: `walk(f)` traverses the JSON entity given as INPUT, and replaces each node it encounters with f evaluated at that node.  So you have to write f to cover all possibilities. As with your example, f normally takes the form: `if type == .... and .... then .... else . end`